# Is this user really a bot?

Tags: discussion, robots, chatbot

I think this [user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1839506/caprica-six) is a bot, but I am not sure. He/she is the administrator of [this room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/ecmascript) (the most popular room). I just saw his/her *About me* section which says:

> **Born: December 24th, 2011. 10:47PM.** I am a bot. Occasionally run by a person, but often just a bot. Don't abuse me and I won't abuse you.

Comment: I'm also a bot.

Comment: We're all bots. This is just virtual reality.

Comment: But seriously - why is this a problem? Said bot has been a perfectly civil and productive member of the community.

Comment: Remember: All bots are humans unless stated otherwise.

Comment: Would we actually know if we were bots though?

Comment: I see where this discussion in comments is taking us... ;-)

Comment: On the Internet, nobody knows what ecmascript is anyway, except bots.

Comment: I guess the bot must pass the Turing test?

Comment: So it's a helpful, friendly bot that provides relevant and useful answers? [Sounds perfect](https://xkcd.com/810/).

Comment: Dammit, they're onto us. ABORT ABORT. unload botman1.exe though botman99999.exe

Comment: Darn it, all these great comments when I'm out of comment votes...

Comment: you all feared to answer

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The only way to bring a 'bot' into chat is to run it through a user that has sufficient privileges to use chat. Therefore, if you want to write a chat bot that interacts with the room, you'll need to get a couple of up-votes, and then the 'bot user' can join the chat room and run whatever bot code is in the browser ready for it.

So, all bots are born human; some occasionally revert when they need to reload rep.

Comment: That's oddly poetic