# What is meant by this design?

Tags: discussion, design

Please first see [Why are 15 reputation points required to upvote?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41347/why-are-15-reputation-points-required-to-upvote?rq=1)

There are so many answers. But in one answer (https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/226994/256103), the background color is changed. But that not deleted and there have I didn't see any information.

See this screen:

[image]

Why? What was the meaning for this type of answers? Or is it bug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See that -5 next to that answer?

Those are downvotes. A bunch of people seem to think this answer is bad or incorrect or so.

The system automatically gives answers with lots of downvotes a different color to make it clear that the community doesn't think these are good and to distinguish bad from good.

Comment: So Why the questions are does not changed the colors?(see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229553/is-this-user-really-a-bot)

Comment: @user256103 - because you only see one question at a time.